# Checking Microphone Volume in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

How to check whether microphone is muted before recording audio in iPhone?

Comment: Are you sure the microphone can even be muted in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't have to. You have to "warn" AVAudioSession that you are going to record a bit of Audio. Doing so, even if you are muted (on the IPhone, I Have not tested this with any external device) you will be able to record your audio... here is the piece of code that does that:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]         
     setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord
     error: &error];
```

it even records with a higher volume.
Best of luck...